# Microsoft Teams - How to launch MS Teams from Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, microsoft-teams

I'm looking to launch an intent to open the Microsoft Teams main activity from my app. I would assume it would be something like `com.microsoft.teams.MainActivity` but this does not seem to launch. Trying to open via URI of `msteams://teams.microsoft.com` takes me to the browser instead of the app.

Is this functionality possible?

Edit: Using adb gave me the following, however this also does not seem to work.

```
C:\Users\Redacted>adb shell dumpsys window | find "mCurrentFocus"
  mCurrentFocus=Window{91c21a9 u0 com.microsoft.teams/com.microsoft.skype.teams.views.activities.MainActivity}
```

Comment: It's `com.microsoft.skype.teams.views.activities.MainActivity`. I used [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.android.developertools) to find out

Answer (score 0):

As Posted by @Nicolas - Use com.microsoft.skype.teams.views.activities.MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to launch the MS Teams application using command:

```
adb shell am start com.microsoft.teams/com.microsoft.skype.teams.Launcher
```

So I think that you can use activity `com.microsoft.skype.teams.Launcher`.